# Postgres COPY FROM csv file- No such file or directory

Tags: postgresql, import, psql, csv

I'm trying to import a (rather large) .txt file into a table geonames in PostgreSQL 9.1. I'm in the /~ directory of my server, with a file named US.txt placed in that directory. I set the `search_path` variable to geochat, the name of the database I'm working in. I then enter this query:

```
COPY geonames
FROM 'US.txt',
DELIMITER E'\t',
NULL 'NULL');
```

I then receive this error:

```
ERROR: could not open file "US.txt" for reading: No such file or directory.
```

Do I have to type in `\i US.txt` or something similar first, or should it just get it from the present working directory?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A couple of misconceptions:

**1.**

> I'm in the /~ directory of my server

There is no directory `/~`. It's either `/` (root directory) or `~` (home directory of current user). It's also irrelevant to the problem.

**2.**

> I set the search_path variable to geochat, the name of the database I'm working in

The [`search_path`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-to-create-table-inside-specific-schema-by-default-in-postgres/9067777#9067777) has nothing to do with the name of the database. It's for **schemas** inside the current database. You probably need to reset this.

**3.**
You are required to use the *absolute path* for your file. As documented [in the manual here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-copy.html):

> ***`filename`***
>
> The absolute path name of the input or output file.

**4.**
DELIMITER: just noise.

> The default is a tab character in text format

**5.**
NULL: It's rather uncommon to use the actual string `'NULL'` for a `NULL` value. Are you sure?

> The default is `\N` (backslash-N) in text format, and an unquoted empty string in CSV format.

My guess (after resetting `search_path` - or you schema-qualify the table name):

```
COPY geonames FROM '/path/to/file/US.txt';
```

Comment: The manual you linked for point 3. actually states that a relative path is ok for input files: `An input file name can be an absolute or relative path` http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-copy.html Though it really doesn't seem to work with relative paths.

Answer (score 18):

Maybe a bit late, but hopefully useful:

Use \copy instead

https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/COPY

jvdw

Answer (score 6):

The paths are relative to the PostgreSQL server, not the `psql` client.

Assuming you are running PostgreSQL 9.4, you can put `US.txt` in the directory `/var/lib/postgresql/9.4/main/`.

Comment: Ah, thanks! This really explains the "relative" part!

Answer (score 5):

Another option is to pipe it in from stdin:

```sh
cat US.txt | psql -c "copy geonames from STDIN WITH (FORMAT csv);"
```

Comment: Great. An old custom scripting mechanism stopped working (file not found) and this did the trick, MMD TY

Answer (score 2):

if you're running your COPY command from a script, you can have a step in the script that creates the COPY command with the correct absolute path.

```
MYPWD=$(pwd)
echo "COPY geonames FROM '$MYPWD/US.txt', DELIMITER E'\t';"
MYPWD=
```

you can then run this portion into a file and execute it

```
./step_to_create_COPY_with_abs_path.sh >COPY_abs_path.sql
psql -f COPY_abs_path.sql -d your_db_name
```