# File not reading from relative path using COPY command

Tags: python, postgresql, csv, psycopg2

I am using postgresql COPY command to insert data from local csv (**relative path**) to postgres table by below command

```
COPY edmonton.general_building_permit_table(permit_date, permit_number, year, month_number, report_permit_date, job_category, address, legal_description, neighbourhood, neighbourhood_number, job_description, building_type, work_type, floor_area, construction_value, zoning, units_added, latitude, longitude, location, count) FROM 'data/General_Building_Permits_01_2017.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;"
```

Am executing queries using psycopg2 python module. I am getting below error

```
Error could not open file "data/General_Building_Permits_02_2017.csv" for reading: No such file or directory
```

But the csv exists in the path. I need to know whether COPY command accepts relative path or not? or any other issues?

Comment: Have you checked the documentation?

Comment: The path needs to be *absolute* and *on the server*. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16618299/postgres-copy-from-csv-file-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-copy.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Postgres COPY FROM csv file- No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16618299/postgres-copy-from-csv-file-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 0):

You need to start from the root.
And use absolute path.

for example your directory should supposed to look something like this.

/home/name/Desktop/asd.txt